# How can I get my Tailwind CSS React JS website to be fully responsive on different screen heights?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am working on a React JS website with tailwind CSS for the first time and I am having a hard time getting the website to become fully responsive in terms of different screen heights.
So far the website works perfectly fine on small screens but when I minimize the height of the screen that's when the components gets mushed together or on top of each other!
Not sure if I can find anything on screen height media queries in tailwind CSS.

Here is the Github repo link :https://github.com/moeabraham/new-portfolio
appreciate your help!
[image: on small width screens, It works!]

[image: on smaller heights it gets mushed!!]

Comment: I believe you might be using absolute positioning, that's why the content is being overlapped on changing the height.

Comment: I am not sure I am using absolute positioning with anything except for the navbar hamburger Menu, I am using an itinerary operator with it. the page crumbles with or without the condition

Comment: It would be good to add your `html` and `css` code here on the question so that the issue is clearly visible.

Comment: this might help https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design